# find the Fourier series of this function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

In the following problem I am trying to extend the function $f(x) = x $ defined on the interval $(0,\pi)$ into the interval $(-\pi,0)$ as a even function. Then I need to find the Fourier series of this function.

So I believe I have extending the function onto the interval $(-\pi,0)$ correctly below.

$$f(x) = -x, (-\pi,0)$$

I am having a little trouble understanding the question. I believe I need to find the Fourier series of this function which is now $-x$. Since the function is now an even function the Fourier series should just consist of the terms $a_0$ and $a_n$ since $b_n$ has sin attached to it making it a odd function and therefore making it $0$

However I am a little confused what formula now to use,

should I use the following formulas? and if so what is $L$? once I get these matters figured out I can proceed myself with the calculations, thanks!

$$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n cos(nx)$$

$$a_0 = \frac{2}{L} \int^L_0f(x)dx$$

$$a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^L_0f(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$$

Comment: The interval would be $[-\pi,\pi]$. The $a_n$ are $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|\cos(nx)dx$ for $n\ne 0$ and $a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|dx$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts okay so would $$a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}|x| dx = \frac{x|x|}{4\pi}|_{-\pi}^{\pi} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts why would the $a_n$ just be $\frac{1}{\pi}$ and the $a_0$ be $\frac{1}{2\pi}$?

Comment: It's from formula.

Comment: @MyGlasses thanks, does my calculation for $a_0$ look correct? its my first time integrating using absolute value

Comment: @myglasses would you inregrate using |x| or just x?

Comment: I think $a_0=\pi$

Comment: @MyGlasses could you possibly show me how you got that for $a_0?$

Comment: With your formula $a_0 = \frac{2}{L} \int^L_0f(x)dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_0 x dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi^2}{2}=\pi$.

Comment: @jh123 With the formula in $[0,\pi]$ we have $|x|=x$.

Comment: @MyGlasses I thought I had to use the formula that was suggested above by disintegratingbyparts $a_0 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^\pi_{-\pi}|x|$?

Comment: $a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|x|dx=2\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}xdx=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{\pi^2}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: In your formula $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n cos(nx)$$
$$a_0 = \frac{2}{L} \int^L_0f(x)dx$$
with @dis
$$f(x) = a_0 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n cos(nx)$$
$$a_0 = \frac{1}{2L} \int^L_{-L}f(x)dx$$

Comment: Thank you @MyGlasses . With the convention $\frac{a_0}{2}$, all of the multipliers are the same for the integrals.

Comment: okay so they are the same answers just using different formulas

Comment: I am calculating $a_n$ right now using your formula, I will post in a second hopefully it will be correct so I will have another problem solved!

Comment: $$a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int^{L}_{-0}|x|cos(nx) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{0}xcos(nx) = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\pi n sin(n\pi)+cos(\pi n)-1}{n^2}$$

Comment: @MyGlasses does that look correct? cross my fingers

Comment: Correct it is.!

Comment: @Myglasses thank god, then using the fact that $sin(n\pi) = 0$ and $cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$ then $\frac{2}{\pi} (\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2})$ is there anyway to simplify that?

Comment: No. fine $\dfrac{2[(-1)^n-1]}{\pi n^2}$

Comment: @Myglasses okay great! so the final answer will be $$f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{2[(-1)^n-1]}{\pi n^2}\cos(nx)$$ thanks everyone for your help! much appreciated

Comment: Ok. $n=1$ in all above summations! Good luck :).